# browse postgres in a docker container

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework, pgadmin-4

I am using docker-compose to work across multiple docker containers, all these containers are mostly individual django rest framework built applications. I have downloaded all the containers and am able to build the whole application using all these containers.

Each container has postgres db running, I want to browse the db now using any ui tool. I know pgadmin can do the work here, but how I can configure my pgadmin to showcase any postgres database from these containers?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to expose your database port also to your local network.

Normally you connect your application containers internally to the database container. In that case it's not needed declare the ports section in your compose file for the database, but if you have that entry you bind your database in addition to your local host.

After you have also expose the postgres port to your host port it should be no problem to connect with the gui tool of your choice.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    httpd:
        image: "oth/d_apache2.4:0.2"
        ports:
                # container port 80 of the webserver to localhost 80   
                - "80:80"
    keycloak:
        # keycloak uses keycloak_db
        image: "jboss/keycloak-postgres:3.2.1.Final"
        environment:
              # internal network reference to db container
              - POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=keycloak_db
              - POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
    keycloak_db:
        environment:
        image: "postgres:alpine"
        ports:
                # container port 5432 to localhost 5432 
                # stack intern is the port still available 
                - "5432:5432"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the port of the `postgres` container is mapped to the host system. The default `postgres` port is `5432`. You can do that with the [port directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) in your `docker-compose.yml`. You are only able to map the port once. So your config file would look like:

```
services:
  postgres_1:
    ports:
      - "49000:54321"
    [...]
  postgres_2:
    ports:
      - "49001:54321"
    [...]
```

After that you should be able to access the desired database with the IP of your `docker` host and the above specified port.

---

If you still encounter problems connecting with a client like `pgadmin` check the following configuration files inside your container.

1. Is there anything blocking your connection attempt? Is your`docker` host behind a firewall?
2. `postgresql.conf` under the section [connections and authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html):

   - `listen_addresses`
   - `port`
3. Check your [`pg_hba.conf`, which controls client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

   - For debug purposes you can set it to the following:

     *Don't do the following in production*:

     ```
     host    all             all             all                 trust
     ```